# Grails run-app: Execute Arbitrary SQL on New Connection

Tags: tomcat, grails, jndi

In production, we use JBoss with JNDI for connecting to the database.  In the JNDI configuration, we have something like:

```
<new-connection-sql>ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=XXX</new-connection-sql>
```

For development, I use `run-app` with the default Tomcat container (Grails 1.3.2) using hard-coded DataSources arguments. Up until now it has been sufficient to approximate the above alter session statement using the `default_schema` parameter in my development configuration. But this is no longer sufficient due to the use of some native Sql statements. I do not want to change the SQL to cater to my development setup (e.g. by extracting the `default_schema` value at runtime). I see two options:

1. Perhaps there is an equivalent `new-connection-sql` argument I can use in my development configuration.
2. If not, perhaps I can move to using JNDI in my development environment.  That would be OK, but looking around I have not been able to find solid instructions on how to do this. In fact, people seem to be having trouble with it. Moreover, I'm unsure whether all JNDI configurations are accepted equally between web containers and whether Tomcat specifically supports some kind of `new-connection-sql` argument.

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to go about this?  Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is the native Sql code I am using (we are targeting a legacy database which uses a trigger to update the DATE_CREATE column and must retrieve it in this fashion on save):

```
def getCreationDate() {
    if (!creationDate) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.query("select DATE_CREATED from some_view where id=?", [id]) {ResultSet rs ->
            rs.next()
            creationDate = rs.getTimestamp("DATE_CREATED")
        }
    }
    return creationDate
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the native SQL a little more?  It is executing against the same default_schema or another schema?  If it's the same can't you just inject the DataSource and execute your native SQL against a connection obtained through that DataSource?

Comment: It is executing against the same default_schema, the issue is that the default_schema setting doesn't alter the session of the connection, it merely fully qualifies the GORM generated sql statements.